# php pagination with eclipse

Tags: php, pagination

This is my first time asking questions on stack overflow. I used this code for pagination and too long numbers for big database. How can I add eclipse for this code. like 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 to 1 2 3 . . . 9 10.

Thanks.

```
<div id="pagination" class="mt-10 mb-10">
 <?
 if($page>=2){   
 echo "<a class='bg-slate-100 px-5 py-3 rounded-md mr-3 hover:bg-slate-300' href='? 
 page=".($page-1)."'>Prev</a>";   
        }       
                   
 for ($i=1; $i<=$number_of_page; $i++) {   
 if ($i == $page) {   
 $pagLink .= "<a class='bg-slate-300 px-5 py-3 rounded-md mr-3 hover:bg-slate-300' 
 href='?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";   
 }               
 else  { 
 $pagLink .= "<a class='bg-slate-100 px-5 py-3 rounded-md mr-3 hover:bg-slate-300' 
 href='?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";     
    }   
    };     
 echo $pagLink;   
  
if($page<$number_of_page){   
echo "<a class='bg-slate-100 px-5 py-3 rounded-md mr-3 hover:bg-slate-300' href='? 
page=".($page+1)."'>Next</a>";   
}  
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.